# Why are the tabs not working using jQuery -3.6.4, Bootstrap (v5.3.0-alpha1)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Having trouble making the tabs navigate. Cache was already cleared. Tried to reload jQuery file as well. Btw, modal windows and buttons not working. CSS seems not to change. Tried to split the JS code into smaller parts and this is the part where everything stops.

HTML:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blocks/style.css.map" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link href="/css/blocks/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/fonts/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blocks/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="menu">
  <div class="container">
     <h2 class="menu__title">Menu</h2>
       <ul class="menu__tabs" id="tabs">
          <li data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="menu__tab menu__tab_active"><div>Tab1</div></li>
          <li data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="menu__tab"><div>Tab2</div></li>
          <li data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="menu__tab"><div>Tab3</div></li>
       </ul>`

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/script.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="js/script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
.menu {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background: #fff;

    &__title {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 45px;
        align-items: flex-end;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #0D0D0D;
    }


    &__tabs {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        list-style-type: none;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 70px;
    }

    &__tab {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 220px;
        height: 50px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001);
        border: 2px solid #D0D0D0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 48px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 0 5px;
        transform: skewX(-25deg);
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.5s all;

        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px $main-color;
            border: none;
        }

        div {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            transform: skewX(25deg);

        }

        &_active {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: $main-color;
            border: none;
        }
    }

    &__content {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 100px 100px 20px 60px;


        &_active {
            display: flex;
        }
    }
```

JS:

```js
  $('ul.menu__tabs').on('click', 'li:not(.menu__tab_active)', function() {
    $(this)
      .addClass('.menu__tab_active').siblings().removeClass('.menu__tab_active')
      .closest('div.container').find('div.menu__content').removeClass('.menu__content_active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('.menu__content_active');
  });
```

Console:
index.html:1

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at DOMEval (jquery-3.6.4.js:133:12)
at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.6.4.js:376:3)
at text script (jquery-3.6.4.js:10231:11)
at ajaxConvert (jquery-3.6.4.js:9350:19)
at done (jquery-3.6.4.js:9828:15)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.4.js:10139:9)
```

jquery-3.6.4.js:4095

```
   Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.min.js:1:1422)
at mightThrow (jquery-3.6.4.js:3802:29)
at process (jquery-3.6.4.js:3870:12)
```

The errors appeared after minifying CSS and JS files.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that we can run to see the error.

Comment: Without looking too closely, I'm pretty sure you don't want your content inside the tab header.  Also your content is missing class `menu__content` which your js uses to display the content.

Comment: Sidenote: why are you using an alpha version of bootstrap? What does this alpha 5.3 do that the current 5.2 doesn't? But on a posting not: [don't show images of text](/help/how-to-ask). That includes images of console output: just copy and paste that text into your post, with appropriate code fences. It's text.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've changed Bootstrap to 5.2. JS and CSS still don't work. The content itself is in another <div> tag after tabs. I need tabs to navigate first.